# How to use multiple container in single page in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, containers, skins, dotnetnuke-settings

I am using a CMS (DotNetNuke) for creating a web application. I am newbe for dotnetnuke.

I searched on net for add or create multiple container for a single page and also installed some package from dotnetnuke site. But there is a issue for add or create a container in a page.

I want to use three container for top, middle and lower container.
Can any one help me out to this.

Note : I am using dotNetNuke 7.0 version on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "container" you are referring to Panes, locations where you place a module on a page?

I would recommend you look at the source code for some open source skins, including my own https://multifunction.codeplex.com/ that will likely help you understand how Panes are managed.